# Publishing custom angular7 library to nexus

Tags: npm, angular7, nexus, angular-library, npm-publish

I am trying to publish the custom angular7 library to nexus repo, but when I am running command **npm publish** it is pushing the complete project dist folder instead it should only push the .tgz file generated inside dist to nexus.

I did the below configuration in project's main package.json file:

```
"publishConfig": {
        "registry": "http://localhost:8081/repository/npm-private/"
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the publishonfig changes in library's package.json and build the library using ng build and once build did npm publish from dist/library folder.